# Is it possible to detect which line, or function triggered a jquery change event on an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, onchange

I know there are manual ways round it, and I have Googled but can find no automated way.

I have some fairly complex code where an element can be `changed` by jQuery in a few different ways, for different reasons at different times during the execution of the entire code depending on various things.

I am trying to locate an issue where it's changing incorrectly and am having trouble working out exactly which `change()` event is changing where it shouldn't.

Is there anyway where I can temporarily add something like:

```
$(document).on('change', '.myClass', function (e){
    console.log(e.functionOrLineWhichTriggerThis);
});
```

For debugging/fault finding purposes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the old trick of creating an error and printing its stack trace:

```
$(document).on('change', '.myClass', function (e){
    var error = new Error();
    console.log(error.stack);
});
```

The stack property is not standard but seems to be supported by major browsers. You can get more information about it here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/Stack

Comment: He needs to know which function is triggered, not about exception

Comment: Nope, that works, the `stack trace` traces back to the function calling the function in which the error was generated, so allows me to look back to the issue. Excellent call, thanks @jjsanchez

Answer (score -1):

you can define variable inside of every function which you desire to trace, then you can make functions set the variable whenever triggered. then you can check value of variable in browser's console and find out which function is used.

Comment: Seems like a lot of work though, I was hoping that jQuery might have an inbuilt ability to do this with the `event` object or something. I can't find anything though.

Comment: I've used the way mentioned above in my project and it's perfect and neat.